# How to create ember-twiddle demo with addons?

Tags: ember.js

I want to create a demo on [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com). But I cannot use some addons with it, specifically `ember-moment` addon.

How can I create a demo with `ember-moment` addon?

Comment: For the one, who gave a negative vote: Can you explain the reason? So that I can change or remove my question?

Comment: This is a great question for stackoverflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `twiddle.json` you have a key named `addons`. You can add any addons there.

"addons": {
 "ember-moment": "4.0.0"
}

Comment: Finally I solved it! The problem is current ember-twiddle is working with ember2.7. But some addons don't comply with it. Changing the ember version is enough for it.

Comment: Addons now working in 2.7 . Reference https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-twiddle/issues/472